# Can't update Array within a function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, variables

Hey I'm working with Swift 2 and I'm trying to make a method that returns an array of strings of IDs downloaded from a database through a query. My problem is that within the function I cannot update my Array, meaning that I can access the downloaded information from the server but I cannot append it to my array for some reason. Or better, I can, but it doesn't really do anything. My array seems to stay empty.

```
func ATMsAroundMe(myLocation : PFGeoPoint) -> [String]{
    var results = [String]()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ATMs")
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myLocation, withinMiles: 5)
    query.limit = 10
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (atms: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            for atm in atms! {
                print(atm.objectId) //Works!
                results.append(atm.objectId!) //Doesn't work
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
        }
    }
    print(results) //Prints "[]"
return results
}
```

So yeah if you have any suggestion or any idea on what am I doing wrong it'd be really helpful and appreciated if you could let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Can u send  "print(atm.objectId)" result

Comment: Sure, the output is "Optional("iLVX8140rg")"

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the call-

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
```

This is an asynchronous call, and thus, your method simply returns as it does not wait for the results that will be returned by this asynchronous call. Thus you will need to think of an asynchronous API ATMsAroundMe in the form-

```
func ATMsAroundMe(myLocation : PFGeoPoint, completionHandler:(Bool,[String]?) ->Void){

    let query = PFQuery(className: "ATMs")
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myLocation, withinMiles: 5)
    query.limit = 10
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (atms: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            for atm in atms! {
                print(atm.objectId) //Works!
                var results = [String]()
                results.append(atm.objectId!)
                completionHandler(true, results)
            }

        } else {
            // Report the failure
            completionHandler(false, nil)
        }
    }

}
```

You can now call this API like-

```
ATMsAroundMe(myLocation){(success :Bool, results:[String]?) in
 if(success){
       if let results = results {
       //Process results
    }
}
}
```

**Synchronous solution**:

```
func ATMsAroundMe(myLocation : PFGeoPoint) -> [String]{
    var results = [String]()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ATMs")
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: myLocation, withinMiles: 5)
    query.limit = 10
    //Declare a semaphore to help us wait until the background task is completed.
    let sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (atms: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            for atm in atms! {
                print(atm.objectId) //Works!
                results.append(atm.objectId!) 
                 dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
              dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
        }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    print(results) //Should print your results

return results
}
```

**Note** Be care full in calling this synchronous API from your main thread, it can potentially stall the main thread until the call returns like any other synchronous calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two things however : the line "completionHandler(true, results)" and the other completionHandler are throwing an error : 
" Cannot call value of non-function type '(success: Bool, results: [String]?)' (aka '(success: Bool, results: Optional<Array<String>>)') "
Second thing if I wanted to create a variable that contained the array returned by the function how would I do it calling the API? Again , thanks a lot.

Comment: Arg!, I had to mention that I didn't test, I will edit the answer with corrections.

Comment: Please check it now @GiulioColleluori

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the main error but I'm still having problems calling the API and assigning the returned  value to a variable outside the API (if that's even possible)

Comment: @GiulioColleluori for your convenience, though not standard, have added a synchronous solution as well. It is not recommended as the call could take long time, and has hazards of stalling the thread from where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why results is not updated is because it is updated in another block scope. So updated values persists only in that block scope. To get the updated result you would need to use closures or `__block` in variable declaration in Objective-c.
which is quite nicely explained here [here in BLOCKS VS CLOSURES](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/from-objective-c-to-swift/)